# Make JAXB escape apostrophe

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, escaping

I am using JAXB to convert Java object to XML. I need to escape the apostrophe  (`'`) character into `&apos;` in the output XML. JAXB by default does not escape the apostrophe character. I learned about implementing a custom escape handler by implementing `CharacterEscapeHandler`. However, I realized this class is not included in Java 1.7. Where can I get the latest library containing thus class? Will the classes in this downloaded JAXB library conflict with the JAXB classes in Java 1.7?

Comment: Just curious: Why? Isn't the generated XML valid?

Comment: Normally there is no need to escape the apostrophe. But we have a requirement that it must be escaped. So I need to find out how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to be dependent on internal classes that will not be available in other versions/implementations of the JRE, you should write your own [`ContentHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) (SAX) or [`XMLStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) (StAX). That way you have full control of the output.

Here is an example. It shows how JAXB normally outputs XML and how to do it yourself with a `ContentHandler`. It's simple, e.g. not very good performance and no namespace support. You'd likely want to write a better version of the `escape()` method. You'd also likely want to write the output to a file, not the console.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyData.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(new MyData("Test < ' \" & >", "Test < ' \" & >"), System.out);

        System.out.println();

        marshaller.marshal(new MyData("Test < ' \" & >", "Test < ' \" & >"), new MyContentHandler());
    }
}
@XmlRootElement
class MyData {
    @XmlAttribute private String name;
    @XmlElement   private String desc;
    public MyData() {}
    public MyData(String name, String desc) { this.name = name; this.desc = desc; }
}
class MyContentHandler implements ContentHandler {
    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        System.out.print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" + Charset.defaultCharset() + "\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
    }
    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        System.out.print('<' + localName);
        for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++)
            System.out.print(' ' + atts.getLocalName(i) + "=\"" + escape(atts.getValue(i)) + '"');
        System.out.print('>');
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        System.out.print("</" + localName + ">");
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        System.out.print(escape(new String(ch, start, length)));
    }
    private static String escape(String text) {
        return text.replace("&", "&amp;")
                   .replace("<", "&lt;")
                   .replace(">", "&gt;")
                   .replace("'", "&apos;")
                   .replace("\"", "&quot;");
    }
    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><myData name="Test &lt; ' &quot; &amp; &gt;"><desc>Test &lt; ' " &amp; &gt;</desc></myData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><myData name="Test &lt; &apos; &quot; &amp; &gt;"><desc>Test &lt; &apos; &quot; &amp; &gt;</desc></myData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the answer from Andreas, I don't like writing my own `XmlStreamWriter` from scratch. I'd advise using the implementation from [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/) and supplying your own `EscapingWriterFactory`. Something like:

```
XMLOutputFactory2 xmlOutputFactory = (XMLOutputFactory2)XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
xmlOutputFactory.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory2.P_TEXT_ESCAPER, new EscapingWriterFactory() {

    @Override
    public Writer createEscapingWriterFor(Writer w, String enc) {
        return new EscapingWriter(w);
    }

    @Override
    public Writer createEscapingWriterFor(OutputStream out, String enc) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new EscapingWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, enc));
    }

});

marshaller.marshal(model, xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(out);
```

An example of how to write an `EscapingWriter` can be seen in [CharacterEscapingTest](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/blob/master/src/test/java/org/codehaus/stax/test/wstream/CharacterEscapingTest.java).